# Adding supplementary (passive) species post-hoc to a CCA ordination by projection

Tags: r, canonical-link, posthoc, supplementary

I have created a CCA ordination using 'vegan' on R. I have three additional species (supplementary/passive species) I would like to plot on the ordination (post-hoc) so that they do not affect the initial plotting of species and environmental variables when the CCA model is being run. I have read that this may be possible using the predict() function and the created CCA model but so far, I have been unsuccessful.

The r script I have used for the dune dataset found in vegan is below

```
library(vegan)
data("dune")
data("dune.env")

# Run CCA
cca_model <- cca(formula=dune[1:27] ~., data=dune.env)

# Create passive dataset
passive_data<-data.frame(dune[28:30])

#predict the passive dataset
passive_projection <- predict(cca_model, newdata = passive_data, type = "response")
```

I have tried to use the predict function above with the following error message showing:
*Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'A1' not found*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: You are indexing on columns, not rows. Is this intentional?

Comment: Do you mean the selection of columns for the species data @Friede? If so, yes that is intentional